# How to add reference between .net 4.5.2 and .net core 4.6 frmaework project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have created two projects in a single solution. One is .net core (v4.6 framework) class library project and the second one is a normal .net (v4.5.2 framework) class library project which is used to send messages to the service bus topic. So far I have added the following reference on the project.js file.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    },
    "net452": {
      "dependencies": {
        "TestClassLibrary": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I add references from normal .net 4.5.2 framework into .net core 4.6 frameworks. I'm getting the following error.

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'TestClassLibrary' could not
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   TestCoreClassLibrary..NETStandard,Version=v1.6  C:\Projects\AzureServiceBusPOC\TestApplication\src\TestCoreClassLibrary\Class1.cs   5   Active

I can't access members and member functions from the normal .net 4.5.2 framework. If anybody knows please let me share your thoughts.

Note:-
I don't know whether the **.net core support service bus** implementation or not.

Regards,
Parthiban

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't reference one console application from another console app.

I'd create a class library, extract the shared logic into it, make it target [.NET Standard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/) and reference it from both console applications.

project.json allows you to target multiple frameworks:

```
"frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": { },
    "net45": {} 
  }
```

Comment: As you said, I have tried but I'm getting the following error when I try to use .net 4.5 class library members and member functions into .net core class library. Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'ClassLibraryNetStnd' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ClassLibraryCore..NETStandard,Version=v1.6. Could you please tell me how can I get it?

Comment: Maybe add more information to the original question. Describe your current project structure and what you want to achieve. Also read this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2016/06/28/running-net-core-apps-on-multiple-frameworks-and-what-the-target-framework-monikers-tfms-are-about/